# Need help filtering mesh spurious points

Tags: plotting

My only goal is to plot the x-intercepts and display their coordinates; however, there is an additional point being added to the first quadrant and the y-value for point a is not zero. How and why?

```
f[x_] := x^5 - 2 x^3 + 1
points = NSolve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]
Plot[f@x, {x, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {f@# &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you do `PlotRange->All` the extra point goes away. I assume this is an artifact of `Automatic` pre-processing your data. You can probably find details in the docs. You could use the option `Epilog->{Red,PointSize[Large],Point/@points}`, then you don't have to worry about Mesh behaving.